# Google Analytics: Traffic sent to another site

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

Is it possible in Google Analytics to see how much traffic your site sends to another site, if you don't have Google Analytics access to the other site?

If not, what would it require?

Many thanks,
Claus

Comment: You might want to look at the autotrack plugin for GA (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/autotrack/) which, among other things, tracks outbound links in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You could execute a function to deliver that specific information to Google via the event function.  For example, this function:

```
function setAnalytic() {
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'event',
        eventCategory: 'External_Link',
        eventAction: 'User_Click',
        eventLabel: 'Redirect to XYZ'
    });
}
```

Would result in seeing the following in the events section of your analytics results:

[image]

See this page for delivering event information to Google Analytics:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#events

Answer (score 1):

You'd be best off setting up an event when the user clicks on your link to the other website.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#outbound_link_and_form_tracking